# NavigationBar title is showing on backbuttonitem when updated

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

i m showing pagenumbers of `pageviewcontroller` on navigation bar as title. when page is turned over technically then current pagenumbers should be updated on the navigation bar.

In my case it is updating currentpagenumbers but page numbers which was shown as title on navigation bar it is showing now on the top of backbuttonitem after updating. why is that. I m unable to understand this.

As of now i dont have any backbutton item programmed on my navigation bar then why title of navigation bar which is actually pagenumbers of `pageviewcontroller` is showing as back button item

this is how i have coded for updating pagenumbers on `navbar`

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
  viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
{
    contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithPDF:PDFDocument];

    currentIndex = [modelArray indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController *)viewController  page]];

    if (currentIndex == 0) 
    {
        return nil;
    }

    contentViewController.page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex - 1];
    _navBar.topItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %u of %u", currentIndex - 1, CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument)];


    [_navBar pushNavigationItem:_navBar.topItem animated:NO];
    return contentViewController;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
   viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
{

    contentViewController = [[ContentViewController alloc] initWithPDF:PDFDocument];

    //get the current page
    currentIndex = [modelArray indexOfObject:[(ContentViewController *)viewController page]];


    if (currentIndex == totalPages - 1) {        
        return nil;
    }
    contentViewController.page = [modelArray objectAtIndex:currentIndex + 1];

    _navBar.topItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %u of %u", currentIndex + 1, CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(PDFDocument)];


    [_navBar pushNavigationItem:_navBar.topItem animated:NO];

    return contentViewController;
}
```

If anyone can make me understand why it is happening. why it is not showing as title as i have coded why it is converted to backbuttonitem.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

It is a default behavior of iOS that in navigation view controller,when the view controller is pushed onto a viewcontroller,then the title of the previous VC is shown in the back button as text of the button.If you do not want to show that ,you can hide the back button item of the navigation bar.